# How do I retrieve youtube videos from a channel without timing out?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I have this program that retrieves videos from a channel and shuffles them, as you can see, the program gets the channel's name from the variable `$playlistId`

```
<?php
        session_start();

        class PlayList {
                public function __construct($id) {
                        $this->id = $id;
                        $this->videos = [];
                        $this->currentVideo = 0;

                        $this->addVideos('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $this->id . '/uploads?v=2&alt=json');

                        shuffle($this->videos);
                }

                public function addVideos($url) {
                        $cont = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

                        foreach ($cont->feed->entry as $entry) {
                                $video = [];
                                $video['title'] = $entry->title->{'$t'};
                                $video['desc'] = $entry->{'media$group'}->{'media$description'}->{'$t'};
                                $video['id'] = $entry->{'media$group'}->{'yt$videoid'}->{'$t'};

                                $this->videos[] = $video;
                        }

                        foreach ($cont->feed->link as $link) {
                                if ($link->rel === 'next') {
                                        $this->addVideos($link->href);
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                }

                public function getId() {
                        return $this->id;
                }

                public function nextVideo() {
                        if ($this->currentVideo < count($this->videos) - 1) {
                                $this->currentVideo += 1;
                        } else {
                                $this->currentVideo = 0;
                        }
                }

                public function getVideoTitle() {
                        return $this->videos[$this->currentVideo]['title'];
                }

                public function getVideoDesc() {
                        return $this->videos[$this->currentVideo]['desc'];
                }

                public function getVideoSrc() {
                        return "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $this->videos[$this->currentVideo]['id'];
                }

                public function printList() {
                        foreach ($this->videos as $video) {
                                echo $video['title'] . '<br>';
                        }
                }
        }
?>

<?php

        $playlistId = "NAKCollection";

        if (!isset($_SESSION['playlist']) || $_SESSION['playlist']->getId() != $playlistId) {
                $_SESSION['playlist'] = new PlayList($playlistId);
        } else {
                $_SESSION['playlist']->nextVideo();
        }

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Video Shuffle</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div style="float: right;">
        <?php
            $_SESSION['playlist']->printList();
        ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php echo  $_SESSION['playlist']->getVideoTitle(); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <iframe type="text/html" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['playlist']->getVideoSrc(); ?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

If the channel has like 300 videos the page times out, how can I retrieve 50 videos at a time like a batch and then another 50 when the first group is done?

I know I can alter php.ini but I don't want to do that now

Answer (score 0):

This is using the deprecated GData API, if you use the new [Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), while [retrieving channel's uploaded videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide#videos-retrieve-uploads), you can set [maxresults](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#maxResults) and get your results with paging, so you can iterate through pages.

Comment: As you can see, the program shuffles a channel's uploads/playlist and inserts one video in the iframe after each refresh, I don't want to use paging